# Converting 31-OCT-17 03.58.50.454 PM to Datetime format using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I want to convert field value `31-OCT-17 03.58.50.454 PM` into a datetime object. Tried searching in stackoverflow but couldnt find this format usage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) with custom format, check http://strftime.org/:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':['31-OCT-17 03.58.50.454 PM','31-OCT-17 03.58.50.454 PM']})

df['date1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%d-%b-%y %I.%M.%S.%f %p')
print (df)

                        date                   date1
0  31-OCT-17 03.58.50.454 PM 2017-10-31 03:58:50.454
1  31-OCT-17 03.58.50.454 PM 2017-10-31 03:58:50.454
```

Comment: df = pd.DataFrame({'date':['31-OCT-17 03.58.50.454 PM','31-OCT-17 03.58.50.454 AM']})                                                                            df['date1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%d-%b-%y %H.%M.%S.%f %p')                                                                                print(df)                         date                   date1
0  31-OCT-17 03.58.50.454 PM 2017-10-31 03:58:50.454
1  31-OCT-17 03.58.50.454 AM 2017-10-31 03:58:50.454                Why is result same for AM or PM??

Comment: Slight changes and it went thru    instead of format='%d-%b-%y %H.%M.%S.%f %p' , I have used format='%d-%b-%y %I.%M.%S.%f %p' . It was needed as my timings are in 12 Hr Format and not 24Hour